# ListFragment, DialogFragment - why?

Tags: android

What is the difference between using [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) and custom Fragment( with ListView in it) elements ?

Same question applies to [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListFragment provides specific API methods to deal with lists. If all your fragment needs is a ListView, is a nice approach to use it. If your layout is more complex, you'd better inflate your own one.

ListFragment usage makes easier to manage a single ListView layout.